# BorderRadius doesn't work without all border sides

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm flutter beginner and I have problem that after applying borderRadius on container its child Widget disappears. 
My goal is to implement this design:

[image]

I wrote following code in order to round bottom left border corner:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(color: fieldStyleColor),
          left: BorderSide(color: fieldStyleColor),
        ),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: obscureText,
        style: TextStyle(color: inputTextColor),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: labelText,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: fieldStyleColor),
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is what result I got:

[image]

I was wondering why my TextFields doesn't displays and I found out that after commenting borderRadius in container TextFields displays normally:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(color: fieldStyleColor),
          left: BorderSide(color: fieldStyleColor),
        ),
        //borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        //  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        //),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: obscureText,
        style: TextStyle(color: inputTextColor),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: labelText,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: fieldStyleColor),
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Result:

[image]

Can anyone help me and explain why my borderRadius doesn't work as I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/mobkit_dashed_border) package (disclaimer: I wrote it) for dashed border. mobkit_dashed_border also provide different round and side of border. There is a example for you;

```
     Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: DashedBorder(
            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
            left: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
            dashLength: 5,
          ),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "labelText",
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

and this is output;

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you. It works exactly as I expected. I still wonder why normal Border doesn't work, do you have any idea?

Comment: Hello, I wrote this package. While writing the package, I realized that border only works with BorderRadius.all() when different border sides are defined. Since I saw this deficiency, I tried to be more flexible in the package. I don't know exactly why, but last time I checked it wasn't possible to use it that way.

Comment: @HamzaVedatCengiz You need to add a disclaimer that *you* wrote the linked package *in the answer itself* (not just in the comments).

Comment: @AdrianMole I didn't understand what I should do. I haven't used stackoverflow much. Can you explain in detail what I should do?

Comment: I added something for you; you can change it a bit, if you want, but there must be something in the answer that says it's your package.

Comment: This post is ***not*** spam but here is a "canned comment" that we sometimes use on posts; the links may be useful for you: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Comment: Thank you for your help and correction. My intention was not to advertise. I will be more careful in my future answers.